# How to deal with useEffect's multiple property change which calls useEffect callback one after the another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a problem with useEffect's default behaviour. I have simplified the code to with some renaming.

Suppose `tookUmbrella` is coming from another custom hook which in the end uses redux's useSelector. And then we have `raining` which comes from redux.

Now suppose there is a button that resets the value in the redux, where it changes the store value like this :

```
{
  raining: true => false,
  tookUmbrella: true => false
}
```

Now our `useCustomHook` will receive this changes one by one even though the redux is set in one go.

So useEffect will run

(1) first with `raining = true`, `tookUmbrella = false`

and at the very next second (2) it will run again with `raining = false`, `tookUmbrealla = false`

But the problem is that it runs with (1) and the toast is shown. So that useEffect doesn't know whether the other flag is already in queue for the useEffect.

```
const useCustomHook = () => {
  const { tookUmbrella } = useAnotherCustomHook();
  const { raining } = useSelector(someSelectorFN);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!raining) return;

    if (tookUmbrella) return;

    toast.info("I ran because it was raining and I didn't took umbrella!");
  }, [tookUmbrella, raining]);
}
```

I could use setTimeout but that is some hacky solution which I would go as a last resort.

At the same time, I don't know how refs can be used here, because I don't want the useEffect to run only when both dependencies are changed. So even storing the previous values in ref wouldn't do too much

Can anyone point me to some solution where I can run useEffect with the updated set of values whenever this set of values are going to change simultaneously